# Inject mocks into spring context WITHOUT spring trying to autowire the mock's fields

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a class which I want to mock for a unit test. The class has a field with an `@Autowired` annotation. I need to inject that mock into a spring context that is being used in a junit. However, even though it's a mock, spring still sees the `@Autowired` and goes looking for an instance of this other class to inject. However, the context doesn't have an instance of that class, because one isn't needed (because the methods that might use that field are being mocked).

I've tried both XML and Java config, and in both cases the mock gets created and then spring still tries to find things to autowire into the mock (note I've set autowire=no in both cases).

XML that I've tried:

```
<bean class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="mock" autowire="no">
    <constructor-arg value="com.stackoverflow.BeanClass" />
</bean>
```

Java config that I've tried:

```
@Bean(autowire = Autowire.NO)
public BeanClass beanClass1()
{
    return EasyMock.createMock(BeanClass.class);
}
```

Note I've tried with both EasyMock and Mockito with the same results.

The only way I've found to do this is to do something like `context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("name", mock)` - but I can't do this if using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Before anyone says "just don't do that", this is for an integration test rather than a pure unit test, and the complex wiring logic of some of the beans means that instantiating a spring context here saves a lot of duplicated effort in the test harness.

So, how can I stop spring trying to autowire beans into the fields of my mock?

Comment: DOn't use class based mocks, use interfaces instead. Spring checks the class for annotations regardless the fact that it is a mock the annotations are still there and hence detected and hence processed. If you don't wan that don't make it a spring bean or use interfaces instead of classes.